# Don't italicize /.../ in this org buffer

Tags: org-mode

Is it possible to specify that, in a certain org buffer, `/.../` should not be italicized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the emphasis in the Org buffer by the variable `org-emphasis-alist`.

The doc of this variable says that you must re-load Org after setting this variable to come into effect.

At least for Org 9.2.6 this is not entirely true.
You can set it as buffer-local variable and it controls font lock.
But, it does not effect HTML-export and LaTeX-export.

See the help for `org-emphasis-alist`. Just remove the `"/"` entry from this list and use it for a buffer-local setting:

```
Local Variables:
org-emphasis-alist: (("*" bold) ("_" underline) ("=" org-verbatim verbatim) ("~" org-code verbatim) ("+" (:strike-through t)))
End:
```

If you pity the lost global modifications of `org-emphasis-alist` you can also use:

```
Local Variables:
eval: (setq-local org-emphasis-alist (cons '("/") (default-value 'org-emphasis-alist)))
End:
```

With the following Elisp code you can also eliminate italic face from HTML export and LaTeX export.

```el
;; -*- lexical-binding:t -*-
(defun org+-remove-emphasis (&optional emph)
  "Remove EMPH from org mode emphasis.
EMPH defaults to \"/\"."
  (unless emph
    (setq emph "/"))
  (let ((type (assoc-string emph (default-value 'org-emphasis-alist))))
    (setq-local org-emphasis-alist
        (cons (list emph) (default-value 'org-emphasis-alist)))
    (setq-local org-element-object-restrictions
        (mapcar
         (lambda (r)
           (cons (car r)
             (cl-remove (cadr type) (cdr r) :test #'string-equal)))
         (default-value 'org-element-object-restrictions)))))
```

You use it in the following way:

```
* Local Variables :noexport:

Local Variables:
eval: (org+-remove-emphasis "/")
End:
```

Comment: Thanks!  A weakness in this particular approach is that it
overrides any global customization of that variable.
So I suppose properly one should evaluate an expression that
removes the `("/" ...)` element.

Comment: @Toothrot I address your concerns in the answer.